# Find a String in a file in Java

Tags: java, resultset, readfile

I search for a way to search for a String in a file.
I have one file called data.csv and it is stored in a variable called actualDataName .

```
String actualDataName = "data.csv"
```

I have multiple metadata files for example `test1.meta`, `test2.info` etc. They are stored in a table in some database and I have stored them in a ResultSet `ResultSet`. In the ResultSet the following rows are stored:

```
DATE      | FILEPATH               | FILE          
01032020  | /path/to/test1.meta    | test1.meta    
02032020  | /path/to/test2.meta    | test2.info
```

For me the column "FILEPATH" is interesting. In each metadata file, a csv file is pointed which belongt to this metadata file. So, I have to find the corresponding metadata filename for each data file. As the structure of the metadata file is not always the same I thought I can search for a String (`data.csv`) in the file and if it finds it then it should say it belongs to this metadata file.
Metadata file structure1:

```
{
"sourceFilename": "data.csv",
"recordCount": "0000320989",
}
```

Metadata file structure2:

```
Source file name:         data.csv
Data Record count:        44
```

I have gone through the posts here and found a way to read the file with a Scanner but it doesn't work.

```
while (r.next()) {
            String metaFilePath = r.getString("FILEPATH");
            String metaFile = r.getString("FILENAME");
            String actualDataName = "data.csv"

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(metaFilePath);
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                if (actualDataName.equals(scanner.nextLine().trim())) {
                    System.out.println("found");;
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("not found");
                }
```

Can someone help me with finding the data file name which belongs to the metadata file?

Answer (score 0):

Create a file object and pass it to the scanner.

```
 File myFile = new File("path/to/filename.csv");
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(myFile);
```

Comment: it actually takes just the path... of the metadata file and it does not look into it...

Comment: Then create a file object and pass it to the scanner `File myFile = new File("path/to/filename.csv"); Scanner scanner = new Scanner(myFile);`